# How to verify hand written signature?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, classification, cnn

I trying to create a model for determining whether a questioned **hand written signature** matches known signature samples, and predict if the signature is **genuine or forgeries**.

I'm guessing I'll have to use a CNN and probably some variation of PCA.

How would you tackle the "signature verification" problem?
Is there an already trained models for that? or datasets?

---

All I could find are research articles, but:

- no GitHub projects.
- no AWS/Azure/Gcloud service.
- no Kaggle completions or datasets.

Maybe I not searching for the right thing!

---

Any dataset of signatures I could use, and ideas on how to approach that kind of problem would be very helpful. tnx :)

Comment: Here is a demo that shows https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/handwriting.html how to recreate a text in a style of a particular persons handwriting. I guess that can also be extended to the Signature (Generation) or Matching.

Answer (score 4):

One of the key features in hand-write is the `frequency` of the signature, i.e. high frequencies - how "shaky" is the signature, and low frequencies - how rounded is the signature etc. 
For that, you would like to use `Fourier` transformation on the image, and train the results on labeled data, if available.

Comment: tnx.. that's a good idea! will use it. 
BTW Wouldn't a deep enough CNN figured it out all by itself?

Comment: Upvote for not suggesting neural nets straight away.